# Regarding incompatibility of the caption package with IEEEtran class

Tags: captions, ieeetran, subcaption

When trying to load the `caption` package with the `IEEEtran` class, I get the following warning

> Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Is there a workaround available? I'd really like to use `caption` and in particular `subcaption`

Comment: I would say, it depends. If you submit the source code (e.g., for a journal), you should stick to `subfig`. Otherwise, the page proof might be a mess. But if you submitt a pdf, you are are free to do what you like. Keep in mind to change the caption font size to `footnotesize`.

Comment: IEEE has it's own style captions and requires certain package options for subfig (see ;page 10 of the manual).

Comment: @JohnKormylo  did you mean the subfig manual or the IEEEtran manual?

Comment: IEEEtran manual.  Sorry about that.